# Как редактировать JavaScript прямо на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html5, консоль, resources

Сегодня решил ради интереса изменить JS код на одном сайте. Сначала полез в интернет искать простые варианты решения. На форумах писали про расширение для Хрома **Resource Override**, однако код не заменялся или сам файл просто удалялся. Так же пробовал метод с AdBlock и еще расширением для загрузки .js файла на сайт. Однако сайт не работал либо ломал браузер... Друзья веб-разработчики тоже не знают. Как всё-таки изменять JS код файла в браузере?

P.s. Если потребуется более точное описание ситуации, я могу обновить пост

Обновлено: Я имею ввиду не на самом сайте, а скорее во вкладе **Отладка или Resources**, цель скорее просто научиться так делать и изучить JS получше

Comment: а какая Ваша цель?

Comment: Вы хотите редактировать код на чужом сайте, что ли?

Comment: не на сайте, а скорее на клиенте что во вкладке Resources или Отладка

Answer (score 10):

В Хроме, начиная с версии 65, есть встроенный функционал локальных переопределений. Он позволяет редактировать скрипты и стили прямо в DevTools, без помощи сторонних расширений.

Все что нужно сделать - это перейти на вкладку *Sources*, слева выбрать подраздел *Overrides* (может прятаться под кнопкой `»`), и выбрать локальную папку для хранения измененных файлов. Вверху под адресной строкой появится запрос на предоставление доступа к папке - нажимаем кнопку "Разрешить".

После этого, можно свободно редактировать скрипты страницы на вкладке Sources/Page - браузер будет автоматически подменять их измененными версиями (которые сохраняются в указанной папке, так же автоматически).  Когда редактирование скрипта завершено, надо только нажать Ctrl+S в DevTools, и обновить страницу.

Быстро перейти к измененной копии файла в дереве папок Overrides (например, чтобы удалить ее, сбросив все правки) можно кликнув на вкладке или содержимом файла правой кнопкой мыши, и выбрав пункт меню "Reveal in sidebar".
Доступен также diff изменений: он открывается командой "Local Modifications...", которая находится в том же контекстном меню.

---

Отключить переопределения можно просто сняв галочку в подразделе Overrides. Конечно же, изменения никуда не исчезнут (в этом и смысл хранения локально) - они будут применяться при повторном включении функции.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете в виду изменить что-то на сайте и сохранить это для вас лично, тогда вам нужно:

*либо расширение браузера как custom style script куда можно вставлять js и css.

*либо расширение юзерскриптов наподобие greasemonkey. Обычно  все используют подобное расширение или букмарклеты чтобы изменять что-то на чужих сайтах.

*либо расширения типа stylish для изменения внешнего вида сайта

Если вы имеете в виду визуальное редактирование сайта и сохранение результатов таких сложных расширений мало, попробуйте  Code Cola, сам я правда не пользовался таким.

Либо сделать букмарклет с кодом который вам нужен для изменения страницы. Один из самых простых вариантов.

Если вы имеете визуальное редактирование своих сайтов то есть много визуальных редакторов.

Можно попытаться подгрузить сайт по ajax (есть ограничение на загрузку из другого домена,нужно загружать как plain text... ) изменить его а потом сохранять в куки или localstorage, то есть создать подобие мини браузера

Другой вариант это перенести сайт в оффлайн граббером и провести изменения уже там.

Есть еще не совсем законные варианты наподобие xss или подмены скрипта... но это уже другой разговор. Я думаю вы не это имели в виду.

Comment: Не нужны никакие расширения. Всё работает без них!

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду редактирование в средствах разработчика, то конечно можно редактировать. Но не все средства разработчика дают возможность сохранять изменения,для  этого приходиться использовать плагины или самописные средства разработчика вроде firebug и прикрутить к ним сохранение в localctorage изменений или использовать расширения.

Comment: Тут имеется в виду именно сохранение результатов изменений  для чужих сайтов, и возможности их воспроизведения.

Comment: Имхо сохранять из браузера на сервер только что отредактированный код - изврат из извратов. Как же тестирование, безопасность, code review  и прочее?

Comment: Я имел в виду для себя лично использовать изменения для чужого сайта чтобы быстро протестировать, сохранять не на сервер а в локальное хранилище браузера. Изменить сайт на стороне клиента и иметь возможность сохранять эти изменения только для себя. Если же надо отправить на сервер, тогда просто выгрузить данные из локального хранилища и после тестирования... загрузить на сервер.

Comment: Хотя и правда в последнем хроме есть возможность делать что я хочу из коробки. Однако я не сижу на хроме потому мой вариант для меня актуальный.

Comment: Это доступно и в FireFox, и в Opera и в Yandex Browser...