# Как сохранить текущее состояние веб-страницы?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension, webbrowser, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-app

Как сохранить текущее состояние веб-страницы в Chrome или другом браузере **вместе с правленными css + html**? Часто делаю правки на своих сайтах, играюсь блоками + меняю стили в целях эксперимента и хотелось бы иметь возможность сохранить данные правки для дальнейшего сравнения с другими версиями одной и той же страницы.
 Подскажите, пожалуйста, плагин или способ. Важно, чтобы .css-файл в `source-вкладке панели разработчика` сохранялся не скачиваясь с сервера, а с учетом того, что я вручную внёс уже в него коррективы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как редактировать JavaScript прямо на сайте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1037044/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-javascript-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: То же самое  прекрасно работает и с CSS. Насчет HTML - хз (не проверял), но тоже должно по идее.